# TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable в python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Всем привет! Я пытаюсь написать команду для бота Телеграм, кусочек:

```
import random
users = random.choice[111, 1, 11, 111] # выбор одного из предложенных рандомно

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == 'Гонка' or message.text == 'гонка':
            if os.path.isfile(f"C://tgplay/{users}_avto1.py"):
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f' {message.from_user.first_name}, 123', parse_mode='html') # "проверка на авто" (проверка на файлы)
            elif os.path.isfile(f"C://tgplay/{users}_avto2.py"):
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f' {message.from_user.first_name}, 123', parse_mode='html')# "проверка на авто" (проверка на файлы)
            elif os.path.isfile(f"C://tgplay/{users}_avto3.py"):
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f' {message.from_user.first_name}, 123', parse_mode='html')# "проверка на авто" (проверка на файлы)
            elif os.path.isfile(f"C://tgplay/{users}_avto4.py"):
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f' {message.from_user.first_name}, 123', parse_mode='html')# "проверка на авто" (проверка на файлы)
            elif os.path.isfile(f"C://tgplay/{users}_avto5.py"):
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f' {message.from_user.first_name}, 12', parse_mode='html')# "проверка на авто" (проверка на файлы)
            elif os.path.isfile(f"C://tgplay/{users}_avto6.py"):
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f' {message.from_user.first_name}, 12', parse_mode='html')# "проверка на авто" (проверка на файлы)
            elif os.path.isfile(f"C://tgplay/{users}_avto7.py"):
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f' {message.from_user.first_name}, 21', parse_mode='html')# "проверка на авто" (проверка на файлы)
            elif os.path.isfile(f"C://tgplay/{users}_avto8.py"):
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f' {message.from_user.first_name}, 12', parse_mode='html')# "проверка на авто" (проверка на файлы)
            else: #если файла не найдено
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f' {message.from_user.first_name},  нет', parse_mode='html')
```

Но получаю в ответ ошибку:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c://tgplay/bot.py", line
> 30, in 
> users = random.choice[111, 1, 11, 111] TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Помогите мне пожалуйста, я новичок! Очень буду благодарен. И да, я гуглил эту ошибку, но у меня ничего исправить не получалось(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`random.choice` - это метод, который принимает в себя аргумент в виде списка.

Измените эту строку `users = random.choice[111, 1, 11, 111]`

на `users = random.choice([111, 1, 11, 111])`

Comment: всё работает! Спасибо вам огромное!!!

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри внимательно (в справке к модулю или в примерах в интернете), какие скобки, сколько и в каком порядке нужны для random.choice.
*Ну и вообще необходимо разобраться, какие скобки для чего используются.*

Comment: @Эникещик, 1 - посмотрите ещё раз, я в коде эту переменную поменял, для конфиденциальности
2 - попробую, но я всё равно уверен что этот модуль и функции у модуля я написал правильно

Comment: Да, проблема была в скобках, спасибо за указание!!